# R data.table, accessing a matrix inside an assignment function

Tags: r, data.table, vectorization

I've the following data.table

```
structure(list(xi = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), yi = c(1, 2, 
3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3), flag = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("xi", 
"yi", "flag"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x11a1a78>)
```

I also have a `3x3` matrix as below.

```
structure(c(1, 1, 0.4, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0.2), .Dim = c(3L, 3L))
```

I want to assign a third column to the data.table `flag` such that if the element in the matrix represented by the `xi` row and `yi` column is less than 1, then `flag = 1` else 0. I wrote a function for this,

```
func <- function (x, y, m) {
if (m[x, y] < 1) {
    return(1)
}
else {
    return(0)
}
}
```

However, if I try

```
y[,flag := func(xi,yi,m)]
```

my flag values are always 0. Could someone point out what I'm doing wrong here?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a custom function...

```
dt[ , flag := as.integer( m[cbind(xi,yi)] < 1 ) ]
```

You do need to be careful to index the matrix in the correct way (using `cbind(...)` rather than `[,]` form of indexing).

Comment: How would that work if we wanted to update the matrix instead of reading it? This doesn't work: dt[ ,  m[cbind(xi,yi)]<-flag ) ] and DT[ ,{m[cbind(xi,yi)<-flag
NULL}], neither. Theoretically you can execute any command in the j part.